# Symfony 2, MongoDB + a2lix/translation-form-bundle

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine

I have problem with the bundle "a2lix/translation-form-bundle" while using MongoDB in Symfony 2.5. I think I've done everything like it was in the documentation, but I have **"The required option "class" is missing."** error.

My Product:

```
/**
 * Class Product
 * @MongoDB\Document(repositoryClass="MyBundle\ProductBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")
 * @Gedmo\TranslationEntity(class="MyBundle\ProductBundle\Document\ProductTranslation")
 */
class Product implements Translatable
{

/**
 * @MongoDB\Id
 *
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @MongoDB\String
 * @Gedmo\Translatable
 */
protected $name;

/**
 *
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="MyBundle\ProductBundle\Document \ProductTranslation", mappedBy="object", cascade={"all"})
 *
 */
private $translations;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->translations = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getName();
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return id $id
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return self
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string $name
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set translations
 *
 * @param ArrayCollection $translations
 * @return Product
 */
public function setTranslations($translations)
{
    foreach ($translations as $translation) {
        $translation->setObject($this);
    }

    $this->translations = $translations;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get translations
 *
 * @return ArrayCollection
 */
public function getTranslations()
{
    return $this->translations;
}
```

And this is my ProductTranslation:

```
class ProductTranslation extends AbstractPersonalTranslation
{
/**
 * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="MyBundle\ProductBundle\Document\Product", inversedBy="translations")
 *
 */
public $object;

}
```

I'm still getting that **"The required option "class" is missing."** error and I don't know what is a problem.

Comment: have the same issue, any updates?

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because MongoDB ODM Mapping creates a field mapping on Reference.

For example, when you have a ManyToOne or OneToMany relation ORM doesn't create field mapping.

So a2lix sees your `object` field as usual mapped field. As the form builder resolves this `object` field like `document` type so you need to provide the `class` option to make it work.

But if you would provide this option then your `object` field will be rendered as translatable field and it definitely sucks.

So please try this:

```
->add('translations', 'a2lix_translations', [
    'exclude_fields' => [
        'object',
    ]
])
```

It will help you with this particular issue.